# why windows headers and linux based headers are different?

Tags: linux, windows, header, packets

I'm developing push notification mechanism with websocket protocol. I tested it to send notification on 2 devices, Android and Notebook (Windows and Linux Ubuntu). And I used Wireshark to see notification packet size. When I tested it I found something bother me. Packet size that send to Linux based (Android and Linux Ubuntu) are larger than packet size that send to Windows based device. Here the screenshot:

[image: Windows Based]
[image: Linux Based]

Based on 2 picture above, I found that Windows Based headers is 20 bytes and Linux Based headers is 32 bytes. Why both headers are different? I need some reference or theory about this problem.

Comment: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol): `The TCP header contains 10 mandatory fields, and an optional extension field`

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. Is that mean Linux Based TCP use an optional extension field? And Windows don't?